# spark sql ambiguity with reserved keyword and regex

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have used spark.sql.parser.quotedRegexColumnNames=true to use regex operation in spark SQL

The same query consist of reserved key word timestamp.

Here is the query

```
SELECT cast(delta.day as string) as day,
       `timestamp` as  `timestamp`,
        delta.`(p_[0-9]+)`
        FROM test_table delta
```

Executing the query is failing with following exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Invalid usage of '*' in expression 'alias';
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.failAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$expandStarExpression$1.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1021)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$expandStarExpression$1.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.expandStarExpression(Analyzer.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$buildExpandedProjectList$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:982)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$buildExpandedProjectList$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:977)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$buildExpandedProjectList(Analyzer.scala:977)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$9.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:905)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$9.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.resolveOperatorsUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.apply(Analyzer.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.apply(Analyzer.scala:758)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:651)
```

removing alias

```
        as `timestamp`
```

from select query executed successfully. I believe there is an ambiguity to resolve the difference between regex and reserved keywords.
Any help to resolve this is much appreciated

easiest way to reproduce the error is executing following queries in spark-shell

```
scala> spark.sql("SET spark.sql.parser.quotedRegexColumnNames=true").show(false)
+---------------------------------------+-----+
|key                                    |value|
+---------------------------------------+-----+
|spark.sql.parser.quotedRegexColumnNames|true |
+---------------------------------------+-----+


scala> spark.sql("select `timestamp` as `timestamp` from test_table").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Got in touch with the Cloudera team and got to know that this feature is being worked upon currently.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12139?focusedCommentId=17346581&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-17346581